# Symfony 3 - There is no suitable CSPRNG

Tags: php, symfony

I'm getting this error on my test server with PHP 5.5 (**Symfony 3.0.9**):

[image]

Everything is all right on my local server created with XAMPP having PHP 5.6. I know that there are two workarounds:

1. *paragonie/random_compat* downgrade
2. changing `random_bytes()` for `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`.

But still, I would like to use them as a last resort. Is there any other way to FIX this problem?

Comment: I know there is a pull request about this issue : https://github.com/symfony/polyfill/pull/44

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, those are 2 of the 3 unique solutions.

As the problem is only in your server (that happened to me too), you could go to your domain and add `/dev/urandom` to your existing open_basedir configuration property in your server configuration.

[Read this article which](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/214/how-to-solve-php-7-0-polyfill-there-is-no-suitable-csprng-installed-on-your-system-paragonie-random-compat) offers 3 solutions (and according to your need only the solution #3 would work).